# Beginner Question: Are the variables in solidity structs state or local variables?

Tags: solidity

I'm new to solidity and just have a quick question regarding structs:

```
struct structName {
    uint256 structNumber;
    string structString;
}
```

Firstly, I've seen structNumber and StructName be called "members", am I wrong to be calling them variables?

Secondly, if they are indeed variables, are they local or state variables?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`struct`s enable you to create data types with multiple properties. `struct`s basically are a **collection of variables**, which can be **of different data types**. In this sense, you can imagine a struct as a **grouping of similar variables** in a **custom data type** defined by you, the developer.

The variables defined in a `struct` are also called **members** of the respective `struct`.

If you define your `struct` in your contract, it is treated as **state variable**, but you can also declare it outside of you contract and **import it in another contract** ([See also example here](https://solidity-by-example.org/structs/)).
You can also use your `struct` in a function, with the `storage` keyword you **access the state directly**, while the `memory` keyword **will copy it in memory**.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract StructExample {

    // state
    struct Person {
        uint256 age;
        string name;
    }

    // accesses state variable directly
    function storageDemo() public {
        Person storage person;
        // your code here
    }

    // copies state variable to memory
    function memoryDemo() public {
        Person memory person;
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is incredibly helpful!

Comment: What happens, when I don’t provide any keyword?

Answer (score 1):

`StructName` is called a variable and `structNumber` is also called a variable. Structs are custom-defined data types that can group multiple variables in a single `struct` variable to form a new type. They are state variables if defined outside a function but inside a contract, and they are local variables if defined inside a function.